# Aggregating Stats When Some Results Are Ignored

Tags: aggregation

This is more of a methodology question than anything.

Scenario: you are trying to report average stats between two different groups responding to a variety of *optional* survey questions.
But, (this is the annoying bit) somebody says "if the number of answers for a group on a specific question is too small (say, less than 2), the result for that question/group should be n/a".

So, Group A has 5 people respond with their ages. The average age is 65.
Group B has only 1 person respond with an an age of 10.

According to the stipulation above, the results for average should be presented/reported as:

Group A: 65
Group B: n/a

Here is my question.  Given the stipulation above, if you are then going to report on the average age of *both* groups, should the data from Group B be included?

Sorry if this is too basic a question, but it's bugging me.  I keep changing sides.

Comment: I think you'll confuse people if you say "Group A average: 65, Group B average: n/a, Overall average: 55.8". This is technically an opinion question (you could do either one and just include a note on the report indicating which choice you made), but if you're going to include Group B in the average, some sort of footnote would be useful.

Comment: thanks, I was hoping there would be a rule of some sort as opposed to it being a matter of opinion... but if that's how it is, that's how it is.